# Teach tripwire or AIDE about renamed files

Tags: security, configuration, version-control, tripwire

In my `/etc` directory there is something I do with files.
Let us say that I am looking at `/etc/passwd`.
What I do when it will be modified is to copy it over, in the following sense.
I have a hierarchy of files: `passwd`, `passwd_1`, `passwd_2`, `passwd_3`, …, `passwd_n`.

Before `passwd` is modified, I “rotate” the files (similar to logrotate).
`passwd_n` goes to `passwd_n+1`, 
`passwd_n-1` goes to `passwd_n`, ... 
`passwd_1` goes to `passwd_2`, 
`passwd` copies to `passwd_1`.

Then I modify `passwd`.

What I would like to do vis à vis a checksum program like tripwire or AIDE is to "let them know I've rotated and allow them to update the checksums but also check that the rotation has gone smoothly.

Do either of there programs provide a way for specifying something like this?

Comment: What about some revision control system?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a real version control system like `etckeeper`. Don't worry about tripwire or AIDE, monitoring file checksums is useless against moderately competent attackers.